# Pyodbc to run saved access queries

Tags: python, sql, pandas, ms-access, pyodbc

I think this is an already-answered question, but the answer below isn't working for me.

[How to execute query saved in MS Access using pyodbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614070/how-to-execute-query-saved-in-ms-access-using-pyodbc)

The below is a simple python code to connect MS Access database.
According to the answer, the created select query should be seen as a View from Python. However, Python complains with this message

The original error message was in Korean. so My Translation of the message is:

> Execution failed on sql 'SELECT * FROM MySavedQuery': ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] is not a valid name. Please make sure that there is a wrong character or symbol in it or is too long (-1002) (SQLExecDirectW)")

Interestingly, other simpler queries except for that one are working with the linked solution.

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

connStr = (
r"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};"
r"DBQ=D:\Documents\Europe\DB\test.accdb;"
)

conn = pyodbc.connect(connStr)


query = "SELECT * FROM MySavedQuery"
dataf = pd.read_sql(query, conn)

conn.close()
```

The MySavedQuery's structure is:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE Condition1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Table2
WHERE Condition2
```

Also, Table2 is a linked-table from another accdb file.

What have I done wrong? The cause is the query?
also the Call MySavedQueries isn't working as well

EDITED: the query works well in Access (also I’ve been using this for more than 6 months for Power BI)

UPDATE: putting pyodbc.pooling = False doesn't make the script work

Thanks in advance

Comment: does your query `MySavedQueries` works in Access? As its written here, I don't think that your query works in Access.

Comment: just change the `MySavedQueries` to a simple sql like `Select * from Table1` and than try to run this query from python. if it works than you have definitely problem in your sql query.

Comment: The question itself has two spellings of your query: `MySavedQuery` and `MySavedQueries`.  So which is it?  Could the error actually be correct that there is "a wrong character"?

Comment: See the tip [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Tips-and-Tricks-by-Database-Platform#databases-containing-odbc-linked-tables) regarding databases containing ODBC linked tables.

Comment: @Tarun.P Thanks for the suggestion. I will try your advice but I think it will be difficult to reproduce this error. At first, I suspected alias of the query result has some connection to the problem, but it's not...

Comment: @GordThompson Thanks for letting me know the official site for the library. I will add 'pyodbc.pooling = False' on the beginning of the script. When I get back to work, I will post the result.

Comment: I notice that the "r" is missing from the word "Drive[r]" in the error message and the rest of the message is an inaccurate paraphrase of what the Access Database engine actually reports, suggesting transcription errors when composing your question. Does the error message really say "... Driver] is not a valid name ...", or does it say "... Driver] '(something)' is not a valid name ..." ?

Comment: @GordThompson  Is your question about the error message wording just for curiosity or does this affect the solution?  Because for what it's worth, the rest of the message also appears suspicious or incorrectly paraphrased: *"Please **make sure that there is a wrong character** or symbol in it or is too long."*  I've never seen an error message that requests that you make the error in the first place.

Comment: @CPerkins - I was wondering if pertinent information had been omitted from the error message as stated in the question, specifically the actual name that Access was complaining about.

Comment: @CPerkins The error message is a translation (as it's Korean). Sorry for all the confusion but please look at the error code.

Comment: @James - Does the error message show the actual table/column name that is supposedly not valid, e.g., `'신분증' is not a valid name ...` ? Also, what versions of Python and pyodbc are you using? If you're not using pyodbc 4.0.24 then try upgrading and see if it helps

Comment: @GordThompson I've upgraded the package to 4.0.24 from 4.0.23 but no luck. Also, there's no specific table or column name. Interestingly, I could see _MySavedQuery_ as a view in Power BI Desktop in their query editor window. I suspect MySavedQuery's complex SQL structure made it difficult for pyodbc to recognized the SQL statement, which is working on other MS program suites.